# NEW (-) BASE = Result Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel

All I am trying to do is Open 2 Excel Files (both Sheet1), that have the same exact structure, but may have different numeric values, read through them and create a third file with "New" minus "Base". If the values are the same in both it doesn't matter if displays a 0 or 0.00 or nothing at all.

Ex: New File

```
Item  Price Discount
 A    10.00  1.00
 B     9.00  0.00


Account
Gross Sales 980000.00
```

Ex: Base File

```
Item  Price Discount
 A    10.00  2.00
 B     9.00  0.00


Account
Gross Sales 980000.00
```

Ex: Result File

```
Item  Price Discount
 A     0.00  -1.00
 B     0.00   0.00


Account
Gross Sales 0.00
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this? Or a reference where I can find something similar? Thank You.

I got the code bellow from a previous example created by co-worker where he does something very similar. I attempted to addapt his code, results so far:

Base File: wherever there is a numerical value is colored red

New  File: wherever there is a numerical value is colored red

Final File: Empty but the same cells are colored with Red and Yellow.

I was hoping there was a better cleaner way of doing this, any recomendations for the following code?

```
 public bool createReport_NewMinusBase (string currentWorkingDirectory, string Book1, string Book2, double tolerance)
    {
        myExcel.Application excelApp = new myExcel.Application();  // Creates a new Excel Application
        excelApp.Visible = true;  // Makes Excel visible to the user.

        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        int maxR = 0;
        int maxC = 0;

        //useful for COM object interaction
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        //Return value
        bool wereDifferences = false;

        //Comparison objects
        object objNew = null;
        object objBase = null;

        //source: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/csharp_excel.aspx
        excelApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;

        //Open BASE FILE
         myExcel.Workbook excelWorkbook1 = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(currentWorkingDirectory + Book1, 0,
                                           missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                                           missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
        //OPEN NEW FILE
         myExcel.Workbook excelWorkbook2 = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(currentWorkingDirectory + Book2, 0,
                                           missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                                           missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

         myExcel.Worksheet wsBase;
         myExcel.Worksheet wsDiff;
         myExcel.Worksheet wsNew;


         //create reportBaseMinusNew.xlsx
         excelApp.Visible = true;
         excelApp.WindowState = myExcel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized;
         myExcel.Workbook report = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(myExcel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

         report.SaveAs(currentWorkingDirectory+ "testReport.xlsx", 
                       Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,false, false, myExcel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, 
                       Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        try
        {
            wsBase = (myExcel.Worksheet)excelApp.Workbooks[Book1].Sheets["Sheet1"];
            wsNew =  (myExcel.Worksheet)excelApp.Workbooks[Book2].Sheets["Sheet1"];
            wsDiff = (myExcel.Worksheet)excelApp.Workbooks["testReport.xlsx"].Sheets["Sheet1"];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Excel file does not contain properly formatted worksheets");
        }

        //Determine working area
        int lr1 = 0;
        int lr2 = 0;
        int lc1 = 0;
        int lc2 = 0;
        {
            lr1 = wsNew.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
            lc1 = wsNew.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
        }

        {
            lr2 = wsBase.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
            lc2 = wsBase.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
        }

        maxR = lr1;
        maxC = lc1;

        if (maxR < lr2) maxR = lr2;
        if (maxC < lc2) maxC = lc2;

        //Copy new data from report into the standard Excel file

        myExcel.Worksheet reportBook2MinusBook1;
        reportBook2MinusBook1 = (myExcel.Worksheet)excelApp.Workbooks["testReport.xlsx"].Sheets["Sheet1"];

        //reportBook2MinusBook.Name = "New";

        reportBook2MinusBook1.UsedRange.Copy((myExcel.Range)wsNew.Cells[maxR, maxC]);

        //Close new data report now that we're through with it
        //excelApp.Workbooks["testReport.xlsx"].Close(false, false, false);



        //===================================================
        //Compare Cells
        //===================================================
        //decolorize and otherwise standardize visual format across worksheets
        wsDiff.get_Range((myExcel.Range)wsDiff.Cells[1, 1], (myExcel.Range)wsDiff.Cells[maxR, maxC]).Interior.Pattern = myExcel.XlPattern.xlPatternNone;
        wsBase.get_Range((myExcel.Range)wsBase.Cells[1, 1], (myExcel.Range)wsBase.Cells[maxR, maxC]).Interior.Pattern = myExcel.XlPattern.xlPatternNone;
        wsNew.get_Range((myExcel.Range)wsNew.Cells[1, 1], (myExcel.Range)wsNew.Cells[maxR, maxC]).Interior.Pattern = myExcel.XlPattern.xlPatternNone;

        for (row = 1; row <= maxR; row++)
        {
            for (col = 1; col <= maxC; col++)
            {
                //Get cell values
                objNew = ((myExcel.Range)wsNew.Cells[row, col]).Value2;
                objBase = ((myExcel.Range)wsBase.Cells[row, col]).Value2;

                if (!equiv(objNew, objBase, tolerance))
                {
                    wereDifferences = true;

                    //Mark differing cells
                    //MessageBox.Show("test 1");
                    ((myExcel.Range)wsNew.Cells[row, col]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                    ((myExcel.Range)wsBase.Cells[row, col]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

                    if ((objNew == null))
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("test 2");
                        ((myExcel.Range)wsDiff.Cells[row, col]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                    }
                    else if (objNew.GetType().ToString() == "System.String")
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("test 3");
                        ((myExcel.Range)wsDiff.Cells[row, col]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("test 4");
                        ((myExcel.Range)wsDiff.Cells[row, col]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Close reports now that we're through with them
        excelApp.Workbooks["testReport.xlsx"].Save();

        excelApp.Workbooks["testReport.xlsx"].Close(false, false, false);

        return wereDifferences;
    }


    /// Determines whether two objects are equivalent
    /// Numbers are equivalent within the specified tolerance
    /// Strings are equivalent if they are identical
    /// obj1 and obj2 are the two objects being compared
    /// tolerance is the maximum difference between two numbers for them to be deemed equivalent

    private bool equiv(object obj1, object obj2, double tolerance)
    {
        if ((obj1 == null) && (obj2 == null))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if ((obj1 == null) || (obj2 == null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        //if both are numeric
        if (IsNumeric(obj1))
        {
            if (IsNumeric(obj2))
            {
                if (Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(obj2) - Convert.ToDouble(obj1)) < tolerance)
                {
                    return true;    //If they are within tolerance
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;   //If they are outside tolerance
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;       //If only one is numeric
            }
        }

        //Now assuming both are just random strings
        else
        {
            if ((string)obj1 == (string)obj2)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


    // Test whether a given object represents a number
    internal static bool IsNumeric(object ObjectToTest)
    {
        if (ObjectToTest == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            double OutValue;
            return double.TryParse(ObjectToTest.ToString().Trim(),
                System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                out OutValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How far have you gotten in your code? Are you able to open an excel and reference the values? Try posting some of your code so we can see where you're at.

Comment: you seem to be asking for a starting point yet you also seem to have code that you say does about the right thing and you just need to modify. Where abouts are you having problems adapting this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
public bool createReport_NewMinusBase(string currentWorkingDirectory, string Book1, string Book2, double tolerance)
{
    tolerance = 0.0001;
    myExcel.Application excelApp = new myExcel.Application();  // Creates a new Excel Application
    excelApp.Visible = false;  // Makes Excel visible to the user.
    excelApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;

    //useful for COM object interaction
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    //Return value
    bool wereDifferences = false;

    //Comparison objects
    object objNew = null;
    object objBase = null;


    //source: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/csharp_excel.aspx
    //xlApp.Workbooks.Open(reportFolder + reportName, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, myExcel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

    //Open BASE FILE
    myExcel.Workbook excelWorkbook1 = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@currentWorkingDirectory + Book1, 0,
                                      missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, 
                                      missing,missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
    //OPEN NEW FILE
    myExcel.Workbook excelWorkbook2 = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@currentWorkingDirectory + Book2, 0, 
                                      missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, 
                                      missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

    myExcel.Workbook excelWorkbook3 = excelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(myExcel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

    myExcel.Worksheet wsBase;
    myExcel.Worksheet wsDiff;
    myExcel.Worksheet wsNew;


    try
    {
        wsBase = (myExcel.Worksheet)excelApp.Workbooks[Book1].Sheets["Sheet1"];
        wsNew = (myExcel.Worksheet)excelApp.Workbooks[Book2].Sheets["Sheet1"];
        wsDiff = (myExcel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook3.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception("Excel file does not contain properly formatted worksheets");

    }


    //Copy Sheet from Excel Book "NEW" to "NEW(-)BASE"
    myExcel.Worksheet source_sheet;
    source_sheet = (myExcel.Worksheet)excelApp.Workbooks[Book2].Sheets["Sheet1"];
    source_sheet.UsedRange.Copy();
    wsDiff.Paste();




    //Determine working area
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int maxR = 0;
    int maxC = 0;

    int lr1 = 0;
    int lr2 = 0;
    int lc1 = 0;
    int lc2 = 0;
    {
        lr1 = wsNew.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        lc1 = wsNew.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
    }

    {
        lr2 = wsBase.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        lc2 = wsBase.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
    }

    maxR = lr1;
    maxC = lc1;

    if (maxR < lr2) maxR = lr2;
    if (maxC < lc2) maxC = lc2;

    //===================================================
    //Compare Cells
    //===================================================

    for (row = 1; row <= maxR; row++)
    {
        for (col = 1; col <= maxC; col++)
        {
            //Get cell values
            objNew = ((myExcel.Range)wsNew.Cells[row, col]).Value2;
            objBase = ((myExcel.Range)wsBase.Cells[row, col]).Value2;


            //If they are not equivilante
            if (!equiv(objNew, objBase, tolerance))
            {
                wereDifferences = true;

                //Mark differing cells
                ((myExcel.Range)wsNew.Cells[row, col]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                ((myExcel.Range)wsBase.Cells[row, col]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

                if ((objNew == null))
                {                            
                    ((myExcel.Range)wsDiff.Cells[row, col]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                }
                else if (objNew.GetType().ToString() == "System.String")
                {
                    ((myExcel.Range)wsDiff.Cells[row, col]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((myExcel.Range)wsDiff.Cells[row, col]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
                    ((myExcel.Range)wsDiff.Cells[row, col]).Value2 = ((myExcel.Range)wsNew.Cells[row, col]).Value2 - ((myExcel.Range)wsBase.Cells[row, col]).Value2;
                }
            }
            else //They are equivalent
            {                        
                if ((objNew == null))
                {
                }
                else if (objNew.GetType().ToString() == "System.String")
                {
                }
                else
                {                            
                    ((myExcel.Range)wsDiff.Cells[row, col]).Value2 = ((myExcel.Range)wsNew.Cells[row, col]).Value2 - ((myExcel.Range)wsBase.Cells[row, col]).Value2;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // Copy formatting
    myExcel.Range range1 = wsBase.get_Range((myExcel.Range)wsBase.Cells[1, 1], (myExcel.Range)wsBase.Cells[maxR, maxC]);
    myExcel.Range range2 = wsDiff.get_Range((myExcel.Range)wsDiff.Cells[1, 1], (myExcel.Range)wsDiff.Cells[maxR, maxC]);
    range1.Copy();
    range2.PasteSpecial(myExcel.XlPasteType.xlPasteColumnWidths);

    excelApp.Workbooks[Book1].Close(false, false, false);
    excelApp.Workbooks[Book2].Close(false, false, false);

    string Book3 = "reporttestpc.xlsx"; //"reportBaseMinusNew.xlsx"
    if (File.Exists(currentWorkingDirectory + Book3))
    {
        File.Delete(currentWorkingDirectory + Book3);
    }

    excelWorkbook3.SaveAs(currentWorkingDirectory + Book3, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                         Type.Missing, false, false, myExcel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                         Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    //excelApp.Workbooks[Book3].Close(false, false, false);

    excelApp.Visible = true;
    return wereDifferences;
}


/// Determines whether two objects are equivalent
/// Numbers are equivalent within the specified tolerance
/// Strings are equivalent if they are identical
/// obj1 and obj2 are the two objects being compared
/// tolerance is the maximum difference between two numbers for them to be deemed equivalent

private bool equiv(object obj1, object obj2, double tolerance)
{
    if ((obj1 == null) && (obj2 == null))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((obj1 == null) || (obj2 == null))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //if both are numeric
    if (IsNumeric(obj1))
    {
        if (IsNumeric(obj2))
        {
            if (Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(obj2) - Convert.ToDouble(obj1)) < tolerance)
            {
                return true;    //If they are within tolerance
            }
            else
            {
                return false;   //If they are outside tolerance
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;       //If only one is numeric
        }
    }

    //Now assuming both are just random strings
    else
    {
        if ((string)obj1 == (string)obj2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


// Test whether a given object represents a number
internal static bool IsNumeric(object ObjectToTest)
{
    if (ObjectToTest == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        double OutValue;
        return double.TryParse(ObjectToTest.ToString().Trim(),
            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            out OutValue);
    }
}
///
```